# Layout is not scrolling when click Keypad android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

[image]

> Login.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_1242_2208"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"

            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

            <TextView
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" 
                android:text="@string/patient_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/patientname"
                android:layout_width="241dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/emergency_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/patientemegencynametext"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text" />

            <TextView
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/emergency_number"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/patientemegencynumbertext"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:hint="021 1234567"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text" />
            <TextView
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="2"/>

            <!--Next-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/whitebuttonshape"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_text"
                tools:textAllCaps="false" />

            <!--Back-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backbutton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text"
                tools:textAllCaps="false" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

> `AndroidManifest.xml` for Login Activity. Here, I added 
>   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` 
>   for scrolling when open the Keypad.But I could not scroll that view anyway.

```
 <activity
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
     android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

> `Style.xml` for Theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item><!--Changes status bar colour-->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

> Here I cannot scroll view when I click Edit text below. I need to scroll full view when the keypad is open. I tried lots of solutions here but I could not find a proper solution for my issue.

Comment: set in manifest file :- `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Comment: Have you try to use android:nextFocusDown properties instead of scroll ?

Comment: Have you tried using android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" in ScrollView ?

Comment: Hi all Thank you,
I tried all of your solutions.But still, I got that issue.

Comment: @Haresh Actually I need to scroll it that is the issue.

Comment: Hi all , Can it be an issue of Theme?

Answer (score 0):

use `TableLayout` instead of using linear layout and

```
scrollview height = match_parent
tablelayout height = wrap_content
```

change manifest to `adjustPan|adjustResize`
its will work

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_1242_2208"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >


        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" //change match_parent to wrap_content

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

//add line to menifests file in your activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine on my side.Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/patient_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/patientname"
                android:layout_width="241dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/emergency_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/patientemegencynametext"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/emergency_number"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/patientemegencynumbertext"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:hint="021 1234567"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"

                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text" />

            <!--Next-->

            <!--android:background="@drawable/whitebuttonshape"-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_text"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:textAllCaps="false" />

            <!--Back-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backbutton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white_text"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:textAllCaps="false" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: can not scroll in my code .I can not identify the issue.What is the Theme that you have used for this?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: I changed  Theme .Still, I can not scroll.

Comment: Yes Ankita.I replaced Your code.but got same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Relative Layout` as parent layout in your code currently you are using `ScrollView` as your parent layout.Put `ScrollView` inside a `Relative Layout` and also add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustRes‌​ize` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. I hope it may resolve your problem.